# Input issue Python

Tags: python, input, boolean

I am writing a program in python, it's very simple I just want to know how to make make the input from a user true if it only contains m, u or i in it but absolutely nothing else. my code runs but if the input is 'miud' it will return true because m i and u are in it. the code below is what I have so far, how can I change it to make it allow only the letters m u and i?

```
x=input("Enter your string")
if 'm' in x and 'i' in x and 'u' in x:
    print("true")
else:
    print("false")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a set for that,

```
if set(x).issubset({'m', 'u', 'i'}):
    print("true")
else:
    print("false")
```

This code makes use of [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) and the `issubset` method.  Since a string is an iterable so it can be used as an argument to `set()`.  The set will contain unique items (in this case each unique character from the input string).

That value can be tested against the known valid characters (also in a set) with the `issubset` method.

`{'m', 'u', 'i'}` is one way of creating a set, but this would work too:

```
if set(x).issubset(set('mui')):
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [all](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) built-in.

```
string = input("Enter your string")
print(all(char in ['m', 'i', 'u'] for char in string))
```

Basically,

```
(char in ['m', 'i', 'u'] for char in string)
```

builds an iterable that yields booleans. For each char in the string (starting from the first), this iterator yields `True` if the char is m, i or u, `False` otherwise.

Then you feed `all()` this iterator:

> ```
> all(iterable)
> ```
>
> Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the iterable is empty). Equivalent to:
>
> ```
> def all(iterable):
>     for element in iterable:
>         if not element:
>             return False
>     return True
> ```

`all` iterates over the newly created iterator and returns `False` as soon as it gets a `False`, or `True` if it gets only `True` values.

The beauty of iterators is that no `True` / `False` list is ever computed: the tests are done on the fly and `all` stops as soon as a char is found that is not neither of m, i, or u. Not relevant here, but this can have a performance impact in some applications.

Comment: That definitely works but could you please explain to me exactly what the code after print does. for me it looks like it is looking for only m i and u in the string and if not then it stuff up but for example what does the word all do?

Comment: I edited my answer to answer this. I'm leaving it for pedagogical purposes but I prefer [sberry's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36696276/4653485).